# Why does my .NET SQL UPDATE only work once?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

For some reason, the code below only actually works one time after firing (and sometimes twice if I'm lucky).

After that it returns a `res > 0`, but the row in the Database does not change. Any Idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

I've already tried disposing the `DbCommand` object (as you can see).

```
public static async Task<bool> SetWallpaper(CornUser User, ulong ID)
{
    using (DbCommand dbCommand = DbProviderFactory.CreateCommand()) 
    { 
        dbCommand.Connection = SQLConnection;

        dbCommand.CommandText = @"
            UPDATE Users
            SET Wallpaper = @Wallpaper
            WHERE DiscordID = @DISCORDID";

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DISCORDID", System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = User.ID });
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Wallpaper", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) { Value = ID });

        dbCommand.Prepare();

        int res = await dbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        return (res > 0);
    }
}
```

I would expect it to actually change the `Wallpaper` column to the `ID` provided all the time.

Comment: Why are you using `TOP(1)`? For me it looks like the DiscordID is not unique for Users and you are updating random row

Comment: And, without an "ORDER BY`, if `DiscordID` isn't unique, then the query above will update a "random" row in the table `Users` with the appropriate ID (which may be the same ID each time, but that is only by coincidence, even if it is *almost* every time).

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I'm very new to MS-Sql someone told me that TOP(1) causes it to stop updating once it has found the first row that maches the WHERE clause for optimization purpose. It might be bs though I wouldn't be able to tell really.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I'll remove it and see if it helps!

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Still no luck so far :c

Comment: The DiscordID is Unique btw, but the query does seem to work at random..

Comment: For a query where you're using a unique ID (which I'm going to guess is going to be (clustered) indexed) adding a `TOP 1` is going to be no benefit. The seek that the data engine performs on the value will be all the data engine needs, and it'll know that there's only one row to update. And if you're updating an unknown number of rows, using `TOP 1` is not going to give you the behaviour you want.

Comment: @Larnu Well at least I learned something useful in that case! ^^

Comment: Please post the table definition for `Users`.

Comment: @LewsTherin [Table Definition](https://i.imgur.com/K6wxCaz.png)

Comment: You appear to have a global shared connection. Do you have global neverending transactions too? Isn't your database in the snapshot isolation mode by any chance? And how do you verify that the row in the database does not change?

Comment: @GSerg So a few observations I've made in the meantime are:
-Unique SQLConnections don't resolve it
-It ONLY happens to updating values, never with receiving them
-It can actually fail the first time too
-Updating the Database in Visual Studio Server Explorer works perfectly fine.

Comment: @MiaAlternativeCorn re: Your table definition. Please edit your question to add information rather than leaving a trail of clues in the comments. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: Are you using implicit transactions (or the `TransactionScope` class)? If so, then it's possible that the transaction remains active (lacking an explicit `COMMIT` or `Complete` call), so the second attempt is blocked by the open transaction.

Comment: @RazvanSocol might be a dumb question.. but how can I tell?

Comment: Whether you are using the `TransactionScope` class should be clear by searching the C# code. The implicit transactions can be requested by using `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` in the Transact-SQL code.

Comment: You can also use SQL Profiler to check what is being executed in the database (preferably, while you are stepping into the C# code).

Comment: @RazvanSocol OMG thank you soooo much. I figured out that all I had to really do is us a TransactionScope and complete it after! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooooo... I found out a solution.

So after a few days of tinkering I completely painstakingly rewrote the entire UserDataService class (that contained these kind of Tasks.

And changed the commands to the following:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            using (DbConnection connection = DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = SQLConnectionString;
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Wallpaper=@WallpaperID WHERE DiscordID=@DiscordID";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DiscordID", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = UserID });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WallpaperID", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = WallpaperID });
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                scope.Complete();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Which seemed to do the trick!

Thanks to @RazvanSocol for leading me in the right direction!